# How to uninstall apt-get?

Tags: apt, uninstall

Since the package manager deals with removing packages, what can be done to remove the package manager (and then install a custom built version of apt-get for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once tried `apt-get purge apt-get` in a vm and it worked, but I would never do this on a real pc. Many programs (for example Libre office) had also been removed.